# Error: "React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child" (Next.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm new to Next.js and I'm trying as per the examples in official docs.

I'm facing an error when trying out the next Layout component.

The `layout.js` file:

```
// To style the layout for the entire App
import Head from "next/head";
import Link from "next/link";
import utilStyles from "../styles/utils.module.css";
import styles from "./layout.module.css";

const name = "Aashiq Ahmed";
export const siteTitle = "Next.js Sample Website";

export default function Layout({ children, home }) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <Link rel="icon" href="/"></Link>

        <meta
          name="description"
          content="Learn how to build a personal website using Next.js with Aashiq"
        />
        <meta
          property="og:image"
          content={`https://og-image.now.sh/${encodeURI(
            siteTitle
          )}.png?theme=light&md=0&fontSize=75px&images=https%3A%2F%2Fassets.vercel.com%2Fimage%2Fupload%2Ffront%2Fassets%2Fdesign%2Fnextjs-black-logo.svg`}
        />
        <meta name="og:title" content={siteTitle} />
        <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
      </Head>
      <header className={styles.header}>
        {home ? (
          <>
            <img
              src="/images/profile.png"
              className={`${styles.headerHomeImage} ${utilStyles.borderCircle}`}
              alt={name}
            />
            <h1 className={utilStyles.heading2Xl}>{name}</h1>
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Link href="/">
              <a>
                <img
                  src="/images/profile.png"
                  className={`${styles.headerImage} ${utilStyles.borderCircle}`}
                  alt={name}
                />
              </a>
            </Link>
            <h2 className={utilStyles.headingLg}>
              <Link href="/">
                <a className={utilStyles.colorInherit}>{name}</a>
              </Link>
            </h2>
          </>
        )}
      </header>
      <main>{children}</main>
      {!home && (
        <div className={styles.backToHome}>
          <Link href="/">
            <a>Back to home</a>
          </Link>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here I'm trying to pass the 'home' prop to my `index.js`:

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Layout, { siteTitle } from "../components/layout";
import utilStyles from "../styles/utils.module.css";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Layout home>
      <Head>
        <title> {siteTitle} </title>{" "}
      </Head>{" "}
      <section className={utilStyles.headingMd}>
        <p>
          {" "}
          Hi ,I'm Aashiq , a Enthusiastic Developer who loves to work on Cool
          Projects and build great things{" "}
        </p>{" "}
        <p>
          (This is a sample website - you’ ll be building a site like this on{" "}
          <a href="https://nextjs.org/learn"> our Next.js tutorial </a>.){" "}
        </p>{" "}
      </section>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Here I'm with 'home' prop rendering the result based on the home prop's presence. I think my syntax is correct but I'm getting this error:

> Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.
> at Object.onlyChild [as only] (D:\Next.js\my-blog\node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:1251:13)
> at Link (D:\Next.js\my-blog.next\server\pages\index.js:682:33)
> at processChild (D:\Next.js\my-blog\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3043:14)
> at resolve (D:\Next.js\my-blog\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:2960:5)
> at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (D:\Next.js\my-blog\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3435:22)
> at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (D:\Next.js\my-blog\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3373:29)
> at renderToStaticMarkup (D:\Next.js\my-blog\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:4004:27)
> at renderDocument (D:\Next.js\my-blog\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\render.js:3:640)
> at renderToHTML (D:\Next.js\my-blog\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\render.js:52:103)
> at async D:\Next.js\my-blog\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:76:329
> Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.
> at Object.onlyChild [as only] (D:\Next.js\my-blog\node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:1251:13)
> at Link (D:\Next.js\my-blog.next\server\pages\index.js:682:33)
> at processChild (D:\Next.js\my-blog\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3043:14)
> at resolve (D:\Next.js\my-blog\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:2960:5)
> at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (D:\Next.js\my-blog\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3435:22)
> at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (D:\Next.js\my-blog\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3373:29)
> at renderToStaticMarkup (D:\Next.js\my-blog\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:4004:27)
> at renderDocument (D:\Next.js\my-blog\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\render.js:3:640)
> at renderToHTML (D:\Next.js\my-blog\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\render.js:52:103)
> at async D:\Next.js\my-blog\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:76:329

My `_app.js` file:

```
import "../styles/globals.css";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe is that empty Link you have in your layout.js?

Comment: @WilliamRizzi,man thanks a lot,it really helped,how blind I am!